# pandas read_csv skiprows not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to skip some rows that have incorrect values in them.

Here is the data when i read it in from a file without using the skiprows argument.

```
>> df    
         MstrRecNbrTxt  UnitIDNmb  PersonIDNmb  PersonTypeCde
2194593              P        NaN          NaN            NaN
2194594      300146901        1.0          1.0            1.0
4100689            DAT        NaN          NaN            NaN
4100690      300170330        1.0          1.0            1.0
5732515             DA        NaN          NaN            NaN
5732516      300174170        2.0          1.0            1.0
```

I want to skip rows 2194593, 4100689, and 5732515. I would expect to not see those rows in the table that I have read in.

```
>> df = pd.read_csv(file,sep='|',low_memory=False,
                     usecols= cols_to_use,
                     skiprows=[2194593,4100689,5732515])
```

Yet when I print it again, those rows are still there.

```
>> df
        MstrRecNbrTxt  UnitIDNmb  PersonIDNmb  PersonTypeCde
2194593              P        NaN          NaN            NaN
2194594      300146901        1.0          1.0            1.0
4100689            DAT        NaN          NaN            NaN
4100690      300170330        1.0          1.0            1.0
5732515             DA        NaN          NaN            NaN
5732516      300174170        2.0          1.0            1.0
```

Here is the data:

```
{'PersonIDNmb': {2194593: nan,
          2194594: 1.0,
          4100689: nan,
          4100690: 1.0,
          5732515: nan,
          5732516: 1.0},
         'PersonTypeCde': {2194593: nan,
          2194594: 1.0,
          4100689: nan,
          4100690: 1.0,
          5732515: nan,
          5732516: 1.0},
         'UnitIDNmb': {2194593: nan,
          2194594: 1.0,
          4100689: nan,
          4100690: 1.0,
          5732515: nan,
          5732516: 2.0},
         '\ufeffMstrRecNbrTxt': {2194593: 'P',
          2194594: '300146901',
          4100689: 'DAT',
          4100690: '300170330',
          5732515: 'DA',
          5732516: '300174170'}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My end goal is to get rid of the NaN values in my dataframe so that the data can be read in as integers and not as floats (because it makes it difficult to join this table to other non-float tables).

Comment: `skiprows` skips the ordinal position of the rows, not the rows that have that value, for that you'd need to filter them out afterwards

Comment: I thought that is what I was doing? Filtering them based on the index value of that row...? Is there no other way to pre-filter them so that I don't have these nans in my dataframe?

Comment: It'd be easier IMO to do `df.dropna()` or just do `df.loc[df.index.difference([2194593,4100689,5732515])]` to filter those rows out

Comment: `df.drop([2194593,4100689,5732515])`

Comment: I'd prefer to pre-filter them of NaNs before they get read in so that those columns don't turn into floats. Otherwise it makes it difficult to join/merge them to non-float tables. Dropping them after the table is read does not help with that.

Comment: You can cast the dtype after dropping, it's just less typing dropping and casting as a post-processing step and probably quicker than say parsing every line before loading each line into a df

Comment: Then use `skiprows` and find their actual positions.  If there positions will not be guaranteed, that kind of logic is much better suited for the dataframe object itself.  There is no need to force it to be a pre-process.   `df = pd.read_csv(file,sep='|',low_memory=False, usecols= cols_to_use).drop([2194593,4100689,5732515])`

Comment: @EdChum, oh, I thought casting it to int still maintained the decimal...never mind then!

Comment: @piRSquared This was a bad example, but the index value in the sample I gave matches the position of the line in the full data file. It's the 2,194,593rd line. Isn't that the position that I should be using?

Comment: Are you sure that it's 2,194,593rd line? if this is so, skiprows like most indexing is `0` based so you should be passing 2194592 to skip that row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example... hope this helps!

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

txt = """index,col1,col2
0,a,b
1,c,d
2,e,f
3,g,h
4,i,j
5,k,l
6,m,n
7,o,p
8,q,r
9,s,t
10,u,v
11,w,x
12,y,z"""

indices_to_skip = np.array([2, 6, 11])
# I offset `indices_to_skip` by one in order to account for header
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col=0, skiprows=indices_to_skip + 1)
print(df)

      col1 col2
index          
0        a    b
1        c    d
3        g    h
4        i    j
5        k    l
7        o    p
8        q    r
9        s    t
10       u    v
12       y    z
```

Comment: Oh, I see-- I think you are right that the skiprows were zero-indexed. Thank you for the explanation! It's working now with your suggestion :)